# Rendering two smaller textures onto a bigger texture

Tags: c++, c, directx

When I render a two textures onto a bigger texture.

Consider:

> - ID3D10Texture2D A
>
>   - ID3D10Texture2D B
>   - ID3D10Texture2D C

If I **first** draw Texture B, the **full width of Texture A** and **then** draw Texture C only on **half of Texture A**. ***Why is that Texture C is erasing the area of itself from Texture B?***

I then draw Texture A onto the backbuffer to see the results.

[image]

### I did some additional testing and found out that the alpha of Texture C is also affecting the alpha of Texture B such that if the alpha of texture C is too low, you can't really see texture B. How can such an issue be resolved? In fact, how could this even be an issue? Because, I rendered C after B. ##

```
blendDesc.BlendEnable[0] = TRUE;
blendDesc.RenderTargetWriteMask[0] = D3D10_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;
blendDesc.SrcBlend = D3D10_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
blendDesc.DestBlend = D3D10_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
blendDesc.BlendOp = D3D10_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendDesc.SrcBlendAlpha = D3D10_BLEND_ONE;
blendDesc.DestBlendAlpha = D3D10_BLEND_ZERO;
blendDesc.BlendOpAlpha = D3D10_BLEND_OP_ADD;

hr = aDXDevice->CreateBlendState(&blendDesc, &this->g_pBlendState);
```

[image]
 NOTE: Texture B spans the full width, but texture C is only placed halfway ontop of texture B. Since Texture B is the solid red image, texture C + texture B should NOT be transparent.

Comment: It is not completely clear what you're asking. Can you show some code and some screenshots? You render the sub-textures directly into texture A, right?

Comment: @Nico Schertler Exactly. Yes the subtextures of `ID3D10Texture2D` are placed onto the texture A of type `ID3D10Texture2D`! I don't want to to put code since DX code is very very long and requires many files to be put up here.

Comment: To be able to help we really need [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to see whats going on. Without it we can only guess (which is usually useless). Try also describe [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). And most universal solution is to use a *graphics debugger* and enabling of [DirectX debug layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj200584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Drop I have put up a picture of the issue. If you guys still need code, I will try to pull up some code that gives me the same issue.

Comment: Nice picture. But now I completely lost on what you want to achieve. Texture B marked as "expected result", then what do you mean by `Why is that Texture C is erasing the area of itself from Texture B?`. Could you explain expected and observed result for texture C? And yes, we still need code, or at least pseudo-code. How do you draw? Quads for each pic? DirectX sprite interface? What's with your depth buffer? Sampler? Bitmap data passed to C is OK? Many questions...

Comment: @Drop. I have Texture A on which I used a quad/shader/shaderresource to render the mountains. So far it worked correctly. I see the huge mountains. Then, I render Texture B, which is a slightly darker image of the mountains. Which also works. But then, I want to render a slightly semi transparent image (white area marked as texture C) onto the texture B (which is the darker mountains). But, due to the blending state. It applies the alpha from texture C onto texture B (which makes it almost impossible to see texture B itelf). However, I can see through texture C onto texture A.

Comment: @Drop Thanks for the compliment on the image :P I try. To make it more clear, I have added another picture of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pretend to be an answer, it's just a guess.

Possible cause of blending issue is a proliferation of states into next draw call.

All DirectX (and also GL) states are not being reset on end of frame, they persists until changed or context reset.

So, probably you have a blend state

```
hr = aDXDevice->CreateBlendState(&blendDesc, &this->g_pBlendState);
```

and you applying it after drawing B, but before drawing C:

```
DrawB();
aDXDevice->OMSetBlendState(&g_pBlendState, ...);
DrawC();
```

First frame draws as you expect, but on next frames `g_pBlendState` is still active. So B drawing without alpha only on a first frame.

What you need is two blend states, one for each blending mode, and apply it each frame:

```
aDXDevice->CreateBlendState(&blendDescForB, &blendStateForB); // no alpna
aDXDevice->CreateBlendState(&blendDescForC, &blendStateForC); // alpha enabled

aDXDevice->OMSetBlendState(blendStateForB, ...);
DrawB();
aDXDevice->OMSetBlendState(blendStateForC, ...);
DrawC();
```

For quick debugging of that issue you can try to apply [ID3D10Device::ClearState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after `Present()`. But just for debugging.

Note, that there are one point counter my hypothesis: blending of A not being touched.

Comment: How can one tell if a texture has alpha?

Comment: @mk1 If I understood correct your question, that is up to artist to decide which objects are transparent and how they are drawing. So it must be known before rendering somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of exact details but remember that OpenGL is a 3D library do it takes into account depth when it comes to determining which object occlude other objects. OpenGL also uses floating point numbers for vertices which means even if the numbers look equal then many well not be. The only safe way to ensure that one object is in front of the other is to draw it so. For 2D drawing generally, it is best to ensure that your objects to not overlap at all.

Comment: Despite the fact that the question was about DirectX, not OpenGL, I agreed that there might be depth buffer issue, so larger texture overlaps smaller one. And best way to check it is to draw them in a way so smaller texture will be always partially visible and not covered entirely by bigger one. Need to say, that there might be also zillion of other problems (or combinations of problems) that can lead to such result. They usually solved by graphics debugging.

Comment: @Drop I believe it is the blending issue, where the alpha of TextureC is affecting the alpha of TextureB